# Can't create Race Condition in Python 3.11 using multiple threads

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading, python-internals

I believe this is a difference in Python 3.10 and above from older versions. Could someone explain this?

```
import threading
import time

counter = 0

lock = threading.Lock()


def increment():
    global counter

    for _ in range(10**6):
        counter += 1


threads = []
for i in range(4):
    x = threading.Thread(target=increment)
    threads.append(x)

for t in threads:
    t.start()

for t in threads:
    t.join()

print(counter)
```

Why does this code does not produce a race condition in Python 3.11?

However, when I change this line to

```
counter += int(1)
```

then the race condition occurs.

Comment: I do not get a race condition, but different results using 3.7, 3.8, 3.10.

Comment: the "different results" are the reflection of the race-condition that takes place.

Answer (score 3):

Based on https://old.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/16mlz4h/race_condition_doesnt_happen_from_python_310/k198umz/:

> In 3.10 an optimisation (introduced by commit
> https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/4958f5d69dd2bf86866c43491caf72f774ddec97
> ) made it instead release and acquire the GIL only at specific
> bytecode instructions, rather than at any of them. In your example,
> your code is a loop of [LOAD_GLOBAL counter, LOAD_CONST 1,
> INPLACE_ADD, STORE_GLOBAL counter], importantly None of these are
> magic "eval breaking" instructions that check the GIL (the final
> JUMP_ABSOLUTE however is, and so each iteration of the loop is a
> potential GIL release+acquire point). That means that the load of
> counter, adding 1, and storing it back, all happen atomically because
> there were no bytecode instructions in this sequence that caused the
> eval breaker to do its periodic GIL release+acquire cycle, meaning the
> GIL is held the entire time. This explains the behaviour you see.

> For example, the CALL_FUNCTION bytecode instruction is one of these
> magic eval breakers, so changing your code to have a def one(): return
> 1 and counter += one() will cause the original race to return.

In this case you can check the bytecode translation using dis and notice the `CALL_FUNCTION` bytecode instruction:

```
import dis

def increment1():
    global counter
    for _ in range(10**6):
        counter += 1

def increment2():
    global counter
    for _ in range(10**6):
        counter += int(1)

dis.dis(increment1)
dis.dis(increment2)
```

Answer (score 0):

### PROBLEM:

There are problems loading your counter `counter += int(1)`. The problem is related to `bytecode`, because there are no bytcode instructions in your sequence to execute the loop,

### SOLUTION:

To create Race Condition in Python 3.11, you need to use a disassembler for Python: [dis — Disassembler for Python bytecode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html). You can import `dis`, because a general disassembly is necessary, then notice `increment_n_1` and `increment_n_2` bytecode. `Dis` is a built-in module that provides tools for disassembling Python bytecode. Bytecode is a low-level intermediate representation of Python code that is produced by the Python compiler and executed by the Python Virtual Machine.

The first increment will be:

```
def increment_n_1():
     global counter
     for x in range(10**6):
         counter += 1
```

The second increment will be:

```
def increment_n_2():
     global counter
     for x in range(10**6):
         counter += int(1)
```

Finally you need to use dis:

```
incr1 = dis.dis(increment_n_1)
incr2 = dis.dis(increment_n_2)
```

Complete Code

```
import dis

#First increment
def increment_n_1():
    global counter
    for x in range(10**6):
        counter += 1

#Second increment
def increment_n_2():
    global counter
    for x in range(10**6):
        counter += int(1)

incr1 = dis.dis(increment_n_1)
incr2 = dis.dis(increment_n_2)
```

Output:

```
  7           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (1000000)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 GET_ITER
        >>    8 FOR_ITER                 6 (to 22)
             10 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

  8          12 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (counter)
             14 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             16 INPLACE_ADD
             18 STORE_GLOBAL             1 (counter)
             20 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            4 (to 8)

  7     >>   22 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             24 RETURN_VALUE
 12           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (1000000)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 GET_ITER
        >>    8 FOR_ITER                 8 (to 26)
             10 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

 13          12 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (counter)
             14 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (int)
             16 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             18 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             20 INPLACE_ADD
             22 STORE_GLOBAL             1 (counter)
             24 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            4 (to 8)

 12     >>   26 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             28 RETURN_VALUE
```